# How to calculate distances between several points along network?

Tags: point, distance, network-analyst

I have several points (bicycle share hubs), and I want to calculate the distance between each of them using a network. I want a CSV/XLS that has three headers: hub_id1, hub_id2, distance.

I've created a network dataset ([after consultation](http://www.aubreyrhea.net/gis/index.php/2010/06/creating-a-network-dataset/)), but how do I get the distance between each of the (blue) hubs pictured below?

I know a dollop of Python, so if this requires some scripting, I'm comfortable trying to apply what I know. I'll be the first to say, though, that I've not scripted with spatial data before.

FYI, [both](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53925/calculating-the-distance-between-points-and-multiple-lines) of [these](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44064/how-to-calculate-distances-in-a-point-sequence) posts ask a similar question, but not using a network grid.

Would love some input! Thanks!

[image: Bicycle hubs and the street grid in ArcGIS.]

Comment: It turns out that what I am trying to do is called an OD cost matrix analysis in ArcGIS. Link [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/OD_cost_matrix_analysis/00470000004r000000/).

Comment: You probably want to use network analyst ( http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004700000001000000).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [pgRouting](http://www.pgrouting.org), using distance as cost function, without much programming. Using, for example, Dijkstra to compute the shortest distance between two nodes in the network (here 30 and 60):

`SELECT SUM(cost) as distance FROM pgr_dijkstra('
     SELECT gid AS id,
         source::integer,
         target::integer,
         length::double precision AS cost
       FROM ways',
     30, 60, false, false);`

With a bit of pgpsql you can iterate through the network and store these distances in a table.